# Log scale for multiple subplot histograms in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a log scale on the y-axis of each histogram using the axis method `set_yscale()` in matplotlib, but it seems to ignore this method when there are multiple histograms created using the `by` key in `pandas.hist()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 2)), columns=list('AB'))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,20))
ax.set_yscale('log')
df['A'].hist(ax=ax, by=df['B'])
```

Comment: How about you use a tuple to unpack the axis for the different subplots? `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplot(1, 2)` https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: @Robert that does seem to work, but it's not a scalable solution if you have dozens of subplots.

Comment: Can you specify the shape of the `subplot` you want ahead of time? `fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 1)` then you can set the scale in one list comprehension: `[ax.set_yscale('log') for ax in axs]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would yield a warning that `ax` will be erased and replaced with new axes instance. Now, this is fine, but your plots are in different axes, not the original one. So you need to work on those:

```
# no need to initiate `fig,ax` to avoid the warning
axes = df['A'].hist(by=df['B'], figsize=(10,15))

# set log scale
for a in axes.ravel(): a.set_yscale('log')
```